# Почему при первом выполнение команды он вычитает получившуюся сумму а не прибавляет

Tags: discord.py

Я сделал код но при первом выполнении команды он вычитает когда должен прибавлять

```
        if message.content.startswith("!работа зелёный"):
            rand = random.randint(1, 200000)
            green += rand
            await message.channel.send(random.choice(random_work) + str(rand))
            try:
                f = open("green.txt", "w")
                f.write(str(green))
            finally:
                f.close
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Сделай мне тоже бот который с каждым его использованием прибавляет мне зарплату) полезная в быту вещь! это не баг а фича!